# Implicit casting for method handler?

Tags: c++, methods, casting, handlers

**Some code**

```
typedef void (*EventHandler) (EventObject* sender, EventArgs* args, void* closure);

class Control
{
void AddHandler(int eventId, EventHandler handler, void* data)
}

class SubControl
{
static void mousemove_cb(EventObject* sender, MouseEventArgs* calldata, void* closure);
}
```

**The error**

```
error C2664: 'Control::AddHandler' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'void (__cdecl *)(EventObject *,MouseEventArgs *,void *)' to 'EventHandler'
```

**Here is the line that produce the error:**

```
control.AddHandler(MouseMoveEvent, mousemove_cb, 0);
```

**Description**

The problem is that MouseEventArgs is a sub-class of EventArgs ! So, is there a way to have an automatic casting and register my method with the precise 'Event args'?

Comment: Presumably `MouseEventArgs` derives from `EventArgs` and your headers are set up correctly so that the code can determine this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ template could solve this problem. Use this:

```
struct Control
{
    //Note this change!
    template<typename TEventHandler>
    void AddHandler(int eventId, TEventHandler handler, void* data);
};

struct SubControl
{
    static void mousemove_cb(EventObject* sender, MouseEventArgs* calldata, void* closure);
    SubControl()
    {
        Control control;
        control.AddHandler(0, mousemove_cb, 0);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You get the error because it's actually forbidden by the language. If it had been possible this would open a hole in the type system. Consider this code:

```
struct EventArgs {};

void f(EventHandler handler)
{
    EventArgs args;
    handler(0, &args, 0);
}

struct MouseEventArgs : EventArgs { void GetMousePosition(); };

void g(EventObject* sender, MouseEventArgs* args, void* closure)
{
    args->GetMousePosition(); 
}

f(g); // oops... g calls GetMousePosition on EventArgs
```

Fortunately the compiler catches this bug.

Comment: Does this answer the question? Is the issue not that `MouseEventArgs` and `EventArgs` are fundamentally different types?

Comment: @acron: No, it's impossible even if one is the base of the other. See the edit.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no automatic cast. Types have to coincide. You can change the signature to the `AddHandler` in two different ways:

1. Set it to accept a `void*` and then do force the conversion to the exact pointer to function type.
2. Convert the `AddHandler` into a template that accepts a type `T` so that it can be called with the correct parameters, `t(sender, args,...)`, where the second parameter is the arguments. However, the call has to convert first the `args` to the correct type (for example, if it is a mouse event, convert it to `MouseEventArgs` manually before calling `t`.